# Remove ^ char from XML file in XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the sample XML file which contains "^^" i need to remove it from all over places.

There is 'n' number of possibility to find "^^" in XML so i can't select based on XPATH.

Thanks in advance.

```
    Input

    <CATALOG>         
    <CD>         
    <TITLE>^^Empire Burlesque</TITLE>         
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>         
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>         
    <COMPANY>Columbia^^</COMPANY>         
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>         
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>         
    </CD>         
    <CD>         
    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>         
    <ARTIST>^^Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>         
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>         
    <COMPANY>^^CBS Records</COMPANY>         
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>         
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>         
    </CD>         
    </CATALOG>

    Desire Output

    <CATALOG>         
    <CD>         
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>         
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>         
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>         
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>         
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>         
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>         
    </CD>         
    <CD>         
    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>         
    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>         
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>         
    <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>         
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>         
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>         
    </CD>         
    </CATALOG>
```

I tried something like this.

```
   <xsl:template match="@*|*|processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|translate(text(),'^^',' ')|processing-instruction()"/>            
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But it is not working

Comment: I have edited my answer and added the code you need. However, seeing your attempt I doubt if I should have done that. You need to have a minimal knowledge of XSLT before you can ask for help here. Your attempt suggests that you do not.

Comment: I am a Developer with programming experience I have done couple of projects in XSLT however yes in-depth knowledge i do not have in XSLT.

Comment: I am not talking about in-depth knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`translate()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-translate) function to remove all occurrences of the `^` character from all text nodes.

---

### Added:

As explained in the comments, you should use the [identity transform template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) alongside an overriding template matching any text node:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" priority="0">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '^', '')"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi @michel, thanks however that will not work as i have "N" number of different xpath and do not know for which we are getting this.

Comment: Yes it will work: Use the identity transformation with an override template for `text()` that uses `translate()` as described in this answer.  Had you posted a [mcve], Michael would have seen exactly where you were having trouble and been able to address your exact problem immediately and precisely.

Comment: @NishantMakwana - [See here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#copying) for more info on the identity transform. Between Michael's answer and Kenneth's comment you should have everything you need to solve your problem. If you still have issues, update your question like suggested (minimal reproducible example).

Comment: I tried something like below <xsl:template match="node()|@*|text()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()|translate(text(),'^^',' ')"/>   
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

Comment: @NishantMakwana Please do not post code in comments. Edit your question and add your attempted XSLT there.